# detecting if a gl_LightSource is enabled in glsl compatibility profile

Tags: opengl, glsl, maya

I am writing a GLSL program as part of a plugin running inside of Maya, a closed-source 3D application. Maya uses the fixed function pipeline to define it's lights, so my program has to get it's light information from the `gl_LightSource` array using the compatibility profile. My light evaluation is working fine [(thanks Nicol Bolas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212933/glsl-gl-lightsource-point-directional-spot-differentiation) except for one thing, I cannot figure out how to determine if a particular light in the array is enabled or disabled. Here is what I have so far:

```
#version 410 compatibility

vec3 incidentLight (in gl_LightSourceParameters light, in vec3 position)
{
    if (light.position.w == 0) {
        return normalize (-light.position.xyz);
    } else {
        vec3 offset = position - light.position.xyz;
        float distance = length (offset);
        vec3 direction = normalize (offset);
        float intensity;
        if (light.spotCutoff <= 90.) {
            float spotCos = dot (direction, normalize (light.spotDirection));
            intensity = pow (spotCos, light.spotExponent) *
                    step (light.spotCosCutoff, spotCos);
        } else {
            intensity = 1.;
        }
        intensity /= light.constantAttenuation +
                light.linearAttenuation * distance +
                light.quadraticAttenuation * distance * distance;
        return intensity * direction;
    }
}

void main ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gl_MaxLights; ++i) {
        if (/* ??? gl_LightSource[i] is enabled ??? */ 1) {
            vec3 incident = incidentLight (gl_LightSource[i], position);
            <snip>
        }
    }
    <snip>
}
```

When Maya enables new lights my program works as expected but when Maya disables a previously enabled light, presumably using `glDisable (GL_LIGHTi)`, it's parameters are not reset in the `gl_LightSource` array and `gl_MaxLights` obviously does not change, so my program continues to use that stale light information in it's shading computation. Although I am not showing it above, the light colors, for example `gl_LightSource[i].diffuse`, also continue to have stale non-zero values after they are disabled.

Maya draws all other geometry using the fixed-function pipline (no GLSL) and those objects correctly ignore disabled lights, how can I mimic this behavior in GLSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I looked at the GLSL spec and I don't see anything that provides this information. I also saw [another thread](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/402360-no-glsl-light-enabled-flag/) which seemed to come to the same conclusion.

Is there any way you can modify the light values in your plugin, or add an extra uniform that can be used as an enable/disable flag?

Comment: Yes, in C++ I could test the enable state of all the lights and pass that in as a separate uniform or reset their values in some way. What an odd oversight in the spec...

Answer (score 2):

```
const vec4 AMBIENT_BLACK = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
const vec4 DEFAULT_BLACK = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

bool isLightEnabled(in int i)
{    
    // A separate variable is used to get    
    // rid of a linker error.    
    bool enabled = true;       
    // If all the colors of the Light are set    
    // to BLACK then we know we don't need to bother    
    // doing a lighting calculation on it.    

    if ((gl_LightSource[i].ambient  == AMBIENT_BLACK) &&        
        (gl_LightSource[i].diffuse  == DEFAULT_BLACK) &&        
        (gl_LightSource[i].specular == DEFAULT_BLACK))        
    enabled = false;    
    return(enabled);
}
```